# Classification by minimum distance

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, classification

I want to classify my data by minimum distance between known centers.
How to implement using R?

the centers data

```
> centers
   X
1   -0.78998176
2    2.40331380
3    0.77320007
4   -1.64054294
5   -0.05343331
6   -1.14982180
7    1.67658736
8   -0.44575567
9    0.36314671
10   1.18697840
```

the data wanted to be classified

```
> Y
[1] -0.7071068  0.7071068 -0.3011463 -0.9128686 -0.5713978   NA
```

the result I expected:

```
1. find the closest distance (minimum absolute difference value) between each 
   items in Y and centers.
2. Assigns sequence number of classes to each items in Y
```

expected result:

```
> Y
    [1] 1 3 8 1 8  NA


Y <- c(-0.707106781186548, 0.707106781186548, -0.301146296962689, 
-0.912868615826101, -0.571397763410073, NA)

centers <- structure(c(-0.789981758587318, 2.40331380121291, 0.773200070034431, 
-1.64054294268215, -0.0534333085941505, -1.14982180092619, 1.67658736336158, 
-0.445755672120908, 0.363146708827924, 1.18697840480949), .Dim = c(10L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10"), "X"))
```

Comment: does it matter if the `centers` are reordered from decreasing to increasing?

Comment: Yes, the number of the centers must correspond with the value, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(Y, function(y) {r=which.min(abs(y-centers)); ifelse(is.na(y), NA, r)})
```

Essentially, you are applying `which.min` to each element of Y, and determining which center has the smallest absolute distance. Ties go to the earlier element on the list. `NA` values need to be handled separately, which is why I have a second statement with `ifelse` there.

Comment: You can simplify this a bit and lose `unlist` with `sapply(Y, function(y) ifelse(is.na(y), NA, which.min(abs(y - centers))))`.

Comment: Yes, that was an artifact before I added in the `ifelse` function. `which.min` returns `integer(0)` if there is an NA input.

Answer (score -1):

This is not clustering.

But nearest neighbor *classification*.

See the `knn` function.